# Dynamically render routes in react-router 5.1

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm trying to convert my manually declared routing components (in Route) to dyanimcally rendered like this:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/cars', exact: true, component: Cars },
  { path: '/car/:id', component: Car },
  { path: '/login', component: Login },
]

export default function Routing() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter >
        <Switch>
          {routes.map(({ component, ...rest }, index) => {
            return (
              <Route key={index} {...{ rest }}>
                {React.createElement(component)}
              </Route>
            )
          })}
          <Redirect to="/homes" />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

I have as well tried the following:

```
{routes.map(({ component: Cmp, ...rest }, index) => {
  return (
    <Route key={index} {...{ rest }}>
      <Cmp />
    </Route>
  )
})}
```

But none of the above results in routes. When clicking on links that earlier works, now nothing happens. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do `{...rest}` instead of `{...{ rest }}` to make it work.

`{...rest}` will destruct the the object whereas `{...{rest}}` will create another object like `{rest: { path: '/login'}}`

```
<Router >
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(({ component, ...rest }, index) => {          
          return (
            <Route {...rest} component={component} />
          )
        })}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```